# Using __declspec(dllexport) in a C function

Tags: c

I am reading some old code that has been in use so that I can take over a project. The original writer is no longer available.

All of the files are `.c` files. Most of the function signatures look the same, and I'm trying to understand what they mean.  Here are a few of them:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) TX_TEST Set_Config_Cal (tTestData *testData, tTestError *testError)

void __declspec(dllexport) TX_TEST Cal_Fall_Time (tTestData *testData, tTestError *testError)

void __declspec(dllexport) TX_TEST Send_Cal_Rise_Fall (tTestData *testData, tTestError *testError)

void __declspec(dllexport) Key_PTT (tTestData *testData, tTestError *testError)
```

I understand that the `__declspec(dllexport` declaration exports the function to a `.lib` file so that the function can be used elsewhere, but what is the `TX_TEST` keyword and why do only some of the functions have this?  What is the purpose?

Comment: Find a `#define TX_TEST` in your .c files.

Comment: @GSerg I'd think it's more likely to be in a `*.h` file, but yes, finding what `TX_TEST` is means finding the `#define ...`

Comment: @AndrewHenle The OP claims to only have .c files.

Comment: @GSerg Sorry, I should have been explicit - that was meant to be a prod to the OP to recheck that "All of the files are .c files" statement.  I find that extremely unlikely, and not looking for `*.h` header files that might be in another directory might be the reason `TX_TEST` is a mystery...

Comment: Yes, I do seem to be missing files, but my main question is, what is the purpose of ```TX_TEST```? It isn't a return type because the return type is ```void```.  What is this used for?

Comment: @AlexaKirk You cannot know until you have found that `#define`.